# Can't get rid of Wired connected icon and also can't access to internet

Tags: network-manager, internet, icons, tethering

I was connected to the internet by USB cable from my phone using USB tethering.

I suddenly pulled out the cable from the phone so network became unreachable in Ubuntu but Wired connected icon didn't disappear from top left corner of my screen.

When I clicked on it and opened the menu, Wired connected options were not there.

Actually the menu is working properly, if I connect to wifi I can see details on menu also if I connect to internet using USB tethering I can see details on menu too but on top left corner of screen Wired connected icon doesn't change to Wired off or wifi and I can get rid of it.

Also I can't access the internet neither by USB cable nor wifi, I can just see details of Wired connection or wifi on menu.

To solve this I tried restarting my computer and I tried *systemctl restart NetworkManager* command but nothing happened.

Once I used this command frequently and my network manager crashed and also everything about internet disappeared from my laptop, including Wired connected icon but after restarting, it came back and nothing was changed.

I did some other trouble shooting for internet but they didn't help and I didn't find similar issues on network.

I can reinstall Ubuntu but I will lose a lot of necessary installed applications and packages.

I hope there will be some other ways to fix it.